# Getting user input with Discord bot outside of a command or event

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get input from a discord server to create a list of numbers. Since I will be getting a list of numbers as input for multiple different commands, I wanted to see if it was possible to make a helper function and get input through that.

However, I ran into some problems:

-When solely passing the Context object as argument to the function, then calling the bot's `wait_for()` method, the following warning is outputted:

```
Ignoring exception in command a_q_d:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\name\OneDrive\Documents\Programming\Python Projects\Databot\quantitative_commands.py", line 11, in a_q_d
    q3, q1 = np.percentile(lst, [75,25])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in percentile
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3706, in percentile
    a, q, axis, out, overwrite_input, interpolation, keepdims)
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3826, in _quantile_unchecked
    interpolation=interpolation)
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3403, in _ureduce
    r = func(a, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 3941, in _quantile_ureduce_func
    x1 = take(ap, indices_below, axis=axis) * weights_below
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'coroutine' and 'float'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\name\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'coroutine' and 'float'C:\Users\name\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py:88: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'data_list_quantitative' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

-I also tried passing in the Bot object as argument, however, the same error as above was returned.

Here is the code from my main file:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import builtins

bot = commands.Bot("/", case_insensitive = True)
builtins.bot = bot

#Command Imports
import quantitative_commands
import combinatorics_commands
import generic_commands

#Events
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as {}.".format(bot))
            
bot.run("Token")
```

And here is the code from the functions I am testing:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def a_q_d(ctx):
    lst = data_list_quantitative(ctx)
    q3, q1 = np.percentile(lst, [75,25])
    iqr = q3-q1
    await ctx.send("Minimum value: "+str(min(lst)))
    await ctx.send("Maximum value: "+str(max(lst)))
    await ctx.send("Range: "+str(max(lst)-min(lst)))
    await ctx.send("Mean: "+str(statistics.mean(lst)))
    await ctx.send("Median: "+str(statistics.median(lst)))
    await ctx.send("Variance (sample): "+str(statistics.variance(lst)))
    await ctx.send("Variance (population): "+str(statistics.pvariance(lst)))
    await ctx.send("Standard deviation (sample): "+str(statistics.stdev(lst)))
    await ctx.send("Standard deviation (population): "+str(statistics.pstdev(lst)))
    await ctx.send("Interquartile range (IQR): "+str(iqr))

async def data_list_quantitative(ctx) -> list:
    """Creates a 1-dimensional list of quantitative data 
    to be used for analysis.
    """
    lst = []
    await ctx.send("Enter values (type 'done' when finished): ")

    while True:
        try:
            item = await bot.wait_for("message", check = lambda m : m.author == ctx.author, timeout=30)
            if item.content == "done": return lst
            try:
                lst.append(float(item.content))
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid input! Must be a number.")
                continue
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send("Sorry, you took too long to give an input!")
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `await` it. Otherwise, you'll get the `coroutine` object, rather than what you wanted, the return value of the function:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def a_q_d(ctx):
    lst = await data_list_quantitative(ctx)
    q3, q1 = np.percentile(lst, [75,25])
```

However, be aware that from the code you gave, that will return `None`. You need some kind of `return lst` at the end.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have to do this for any function inside an asynchronous function, or only functions that are asynchronous themselves?

Comment: Only async functions can/should be awaited. You can still safely use normal calls (and you have to) in async functions, for example `len([1, 2, 3])` is not async, but `await ctx.send('hello')` is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with add parameters in your function. For example:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def a_q_d(ctx,num1:int, string1:str):
"""
your code here
"""
```

so your command will be seem like this:
/a_q_d 1 hello

or you can try to catch messages with "on_message" event

A part from these, maybe there is no way to do this.